# Jquery Datatable sorting not working while ajax data load

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, datatables

Jquery Datatable sorting not working for ajax data load

```
index.php

<div> Select Department :
  <select  name='st'  onChange="selectdep(this.value)" >
    <option value="">Choose option</option>
    <?php
     $query_depname = mysqli_query($con,"select d.department_id,d.dept_short_name from t_dep d,t_user e where e.user_user_name like '$user_name' and d.dept_status = 'A'" );
      $rows_depname = mysqli_num_rows($query_depname);
      if ($rows_depname > 0) {
    ?>
    <?php
       while($dep_names = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_depname)) {
    ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $dep_names["department_id"];  ?>">
      <?php
    echo $dep_names["dept_short_name"];
    ?>
    </option>
    <?php
      }
    }
    ?>
  </select>
</div>
<span id="txtHint"></span>
```

When user select the department from the above select options, table data will update as per department selection

```
ajax call script 

<script type="text/javascript">
  function selectdep(str) { 
    if (str=="") {
      document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
      return;
    }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { 
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
          document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
      }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","data.php?st="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
  }
</script>
```

Bellow data.php

```
   <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="stdtable" id="emptable">
     <colgroup>
       <col class="con0" />
       <col class="con1" />
       <col class="con0" />
       <col class="con1" />
       <col class="con0" />
       <col class="con1" />
     </colgroup>
     <thead>
       <tr>
         <th class="head0">S.No</th>
         <th class="head1">First Name</th>
         <th class="head0">Last Name</th>
         <th class="head1">Gender</th>
         <th class="head0">Mobile</th>
         <th class="head1">Department</th>
         <th class="head0">Designation</th>
         <th class="head1 no-sort">Edit</th>
       </tr>
     </thead>
     <tfoot>
       <tr>
         <th class="head0">S.No</th>
         <th class="head1">First Name</th>
         <th class="head0">Last Name</th>
         <th class="head1">Gender</th>
         <th class="head0">Mobile Number</th>
         <th class="head1">Department</th>
         <th class="head0">Designation</th>
         <th class="head1">Edit</th>
       </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
     <?php 
       session_start();
       $st =$_GET['st'];
      include_once("includes/dbConnect.inc.php"); 
      $sql= mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM t_emp e, t_account a , t_addr ad, t_dep d where e.employee_id = a.acc_employee_id and e.employee_id = ad.addr_employee_id and e.emp_department_id =d.department_id and e.emp_department_id like '%".$st."%' ");
      $select_dep= mysqli_num_rows($sql);
      if ($select_dep > 0){
        $i=1;
        while($select_dep = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)){
          echo "<tr>";
          echo "<td>".$i++."</td>
          <td>".$select_dep["emp_first_name"]."".$select_dep["emp_middle_name"]."</td>
          <td> ".$select_dep["emp_last_name"]."</td>
          <td> ".$select_dep["emp_gender"]."</td>
          <td> ".$select_dep["emp_mobile_num"]."</td>
          <td> ".$select_dep["dept_short_name"]."</td>
          <td> ".$select_dep["emp_experience"]."</td>
          <td><a class='edit_link' href='employee_edit.php?id=$select_dep[e_id]''></a></td> ";
          echo "</tr>";
        } 
      } 
      else {
        echo "0 Results";
      }
     ?>
   </tbody>
 </table>
```

And I included all required jquery files. If I place just static table sorting and pagination working perfect where as when I use above code just table displaying without sorting and pagination.
Can any one please help me out this problem, any suggestion will be appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: Looks as though you're filtering on the change of the select input? When the page first loads does it include all the data? If it does then there's no need to get more data from the server in order to populate the table again, simply filter out all rows without your figure.

Comment: Ahh, after looking at your code it seems as though you're refreshing the page after changing the select option? Rather than doing this you could move the bulk of your select to an ajax call and call the server for new data when the select changes...

Comment: so where do you initialise the dataTable?